# Unable to install Ubuntu(s) on ASUS K53SM

Tags: installation, asus

I am unable to install any version of Ubuntu. I tried Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04 beta. But the installation process terminates immediately after the splash screen, stating `termination signal 9`.

Can someone please to guide me to solve this problem?

I have checked the downloaded `iso` file, its fine. I used the same `iso` file to create "Startup disk" and installed Ubuntu on another system.

Comment: Double check the raid settings in BIOS
Try an older build of Ubuntu to see if it works.

If you just choose to boot to the Install CD and try ubuntu without installing does it work?

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I found, after a little research. Your laptop has NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 630M with Optimus technology and I suppose that this last one causes the problem. I found [in this question on the italian Ubuntuforums](http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/index.php?topic=511726.msg4003382) that you should disable the switchable video card setting in your BIOS and choose either Nvidia only or the integrated Intel video card. After that, the boot with the Ubuntu ISO should work, because Ubuntu still doesn't support decently the Optimus technology.

If this is or is not your problem, I think you should report a bug in [Launchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) and explain your eventual solution and see if there is also a better solution and also to show evidence of the problem, in order to fix it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same lap K53SM-SX130D (India). I had ran into the same problem and have hence succesfully installed 11.04. Bumblebee (nvidia Optimus for Linux).

Do these while booting from cd give these boot options **acpi=off noapic nolapic**.
Even though I'm now running only with **nolapic**.

Then I selected text install and installed a base system with X

**I believe lightdm & plymouth has issues so don't install both**

install gdm and gnome classic. I don't like unity!

I am still having problem with **plymouth** so hasn't installed that also.

If after install you are having problems with booting. My system used to hang.
Press **e** in grub menu and add the boot options
Then once inside os edit **/etc/default/grub**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nolapic "
```

or give the complete as given on install cd boot

**Warning:** acpi off means you will lose all power saving/optimizing features

Hope this helps

-Vemman

Answer (score 0):

May be its very late response but I also faced same issue yesterday while installing ubunut 13.10 64 bit on ASUS K53SM with Windows 7.

But I was able to install it .Yes its Possible.

I don't think it has anything to do with your  NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 630M card.

The problem is with your Hard Drive Set up.

Steps I followed to Install:
1.I had C drive (Windows 7) of 100 Gb.

2.**I transferred all important data to my portable hard disk** and created other partition of the rest of the space(Its Empty).

3.Now I inserted bootable  pen drive and started to install ubuntu.

4.I was greeted with screen of install options

a. Ubuntu along with Win 7

b. Delete Win 7 and complete install Ubuntu

c. Something else (i.e. self partition)

1. Now here first I selected option a and boom black screen and Reboot
2. Again same process I did and now **I selected option C i.e self partition.**

7.I choose empty partition , formatted it with EXT4 with size 40 Gb and mount point as root i.e \   (at bottom there is + - Change option for partioning)

8.Then I formatted remaining space for SWAP i.e 4 Gb since my ram is 4 Gb

9.Then I formatted reaming space with few drive I needed. you can do as you wish this step not necessary

10.Now I selected  the root partition i.e EXT4 formatted 40 Gb for ubuntu installation
    and **I installed it successfully.**